# Sort Method missing on new install of Excel 2016

Tags: excel, vba, excel-2016

There seems to be something wrong with Excel as installed on one of the computers in our office.

I have VBA code that sorts a specific sheet. On that machine, I get a Runtime 9 or Runtime 438 error.

I recorded a Sort macro using the Developer Toolbar. I found that the .Sort method is missing from that machine. See the code that does not work below. Note the missing ".Sort" and double period in between ("RSVP Report") and SetFirstPriority.

```
Sub Macro1()
'
' Macro1 Macro

ActiveSheet.("RSVP Report")..SetFirstPriority.
ActiveSheet.("RSVP Report")..SetFirstPriority.Add  := Range("A2:A23"), Value _
    := xlSortOnValues, Query := xlDescending,  := xlSortNormal
ActiveSheet.("RSVP Report")..SetFirstPriority.Add  := Range("C2:C23"), Value _
    := xlSortOnValues, Query := xlAscending,  := xlSortNormal
ActiveSheet.("RSVP Report")..SetFirstPriority.Add  := Range("B2:B23"), Value _
    := xlSortOnValues, Query := xlAscending,  := xlSortNormal
With ActiveSheet.("RSVP Report").
    .SetLastPriority Range("A1:P23")
    .StopIfTrue = xlYes
    .Type = False
    . = xlTopToBottom
    .ScopeType = xlPinYin
    .Delete
End With
End Sub
```

See code that works and was recorded on my machine. Note the presence of .Sort.

```
Sub Macro2()
'
' Macro2 Macro

Range("A1:P23").Select
ActiveWorkbook.Worksheets("RSVP Report").Sort.SortFields.Clear
ActiveWorkbook.Worksheets("RSVP Report").Sort.SortFields.Add Key:=Range( _
    "A2:A23"), SortOn:=xlSortOnValues, Order:=xlDescending, DataOption:= _
    xlSortNormal
ActiveWorkbook.Worksheets("RSVP Report").Sort.SortFields.Add Key:=Range( _
    "C2:C23"), SortOn:=xlSortOnValues, Order:=xlAscending, DataOption:= _
    xlSortNormal
ActiveWorkbook.Worksheets("RSVP Report").Sort.SortFields.Add Key:=Range( _
    "B2:B23"), SortOn:=xlSortOnValues, Order:=xlAscending, DataOption:= _
    xlSortNormal
With ActiveWorkbook.Worksheets("RSVP Report").Sort
    .SetRange Range("A1:P23")
    .Header = xlYes
    .MatchCase = False
    .Orientation = xlTopToBottom
    .SortMethod = xlPinYin
    .Apply
End With
End Sub
```

Looking at the Installation Options, everything seems to be the same between the two machines. How can I add the missing modules?

Hopefully the responses will not be "uninstall and reinstall." I'm trying to get around involving our Tech department because their solution may not be timely or helpful.

Comment: First time I have seen that, I have had issues where the macro recorder will not record "SaveAS" on a certain computer and another computer would not record the conditional formatting as well. I have never been able to find out why or a solution.

Answer (score 1):

This is solved, although the solution remains a mystery.  After several uninstallations/installations/repairs of office 2010 and 2016, culminating in running a .NET fix from MS, Excel 2016 macro sort operations are working now.  I suspect the .NET fix (https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/framework/install/repair) may have been the solution all along, although I didn't receive any errors indicating a need for it until deep into the un|install and repair operations.

Answer (score 0):

Does the workbook have any missing references on the computer where Sort isn't showing? I've had issues where missing references had completely unrelated functions stop being recognised at runtime. Perhaps this can also affect macro recorder.

Answer (score 0):

I have the same issue on a machine with a new Office 2016 installation, running macro code written in Office 2010.  I tried recording the sort routine in Excel 2016 and got the same results as those shown in the original post.

I have since found that the code works on a different Office 2016 machine, but one where Office was upgraded from 2010 to 2016.  2016 is the only version ever installed on the broken machine. The upgraded machine has both OFFICE14 and OFFICE16 files in the "C:\Program Files (x86)\Common Files\Microsoft Shared" structure.  The broken machine has only OFFICE16.  Copying the OFFICE14 files to the broken machine didn't help.

While I can probably fix this by uninstalling 2016, then installing 2010 and upgrading to 2016, it sure seems there ought to be a better way.  If anyone has a better way to fix this, please let us know!  Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

Having 2010 previously installed is NOT the solution.  I downloaded the MS Windows 10 version 1809 installation media and installed Win10 Pro on a new virtual machine, then installed all Windows updates to bring it as close as possible to my problem PC.  Then I installed Office 2016 and the macro works fine.  Since then I have compared...

- Installed apps - the VM has a bunch of bloatware games that the PC
  does not (thanks MS!).  Other than that, nothing is on the VM that
  the PC does not have.
- Installed Optional Features - if it's on the VM, its also on the PC.
- The features installed for Office 2016 - they are identical
- Via Control Panel -> Programs and Features - again, if it's on the VM, it's on the PC.
- Via Control Panel -> Programs and Features -> Turn Windows Features on and off - the VM did NOT have .NET Framework 3.5 enabled, so I enabled it, rebooted, and the macro still works.

Oh, and for the sake of documenting it, I ran a Repair on the Office installation, which didn't help.

So the mystery lives on.  The problem PC is a Dell machine with an OEM installed copy of Windows Home that I've upgraded to Pro.  Next steps (unless someone has a solution before I get there) include finding a spare HD and doing a system restore to factory specs to see if the problem might be with the OEM Windows installation.